# rails carrierwave_direct unable to render direct_upload_form_for form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, amazon-s3, carrierwave, fog

I'm try to set up carrierwave_direct for some image uploading in my rails 3.2 application but seem unable to render the form by using the direct_upload_form_for tags.

I'm getting the error "undefined method `direct_fog_url' for #< PostmarkerImage:0x007fdbe07b39f0 >" when loading the page containing the form.

PostmarkerImage is the model in which I've mounted the uploader like so:

```
class PostmarkerImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :image, :image_cache

  belongs_to :postmarker

  validates :image, :presence => true

  mount_uploader :image, PostmarkerImageUploader
end
```

The image column is a string and I've also ensured that the migration has been run to create the column. The uploader now looks like this:

```
class PostmarkerImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWaveDirect::Uploader

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Include the Sprockets helpers for Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
  include Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper
  include Sprockets::Helpers::IsolatedHelper

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  # storage :file
  # storage :fog

  include CarrierWave::MimeTypes
  process :set_content_type

  # Provide a default URL as a default if there hasn't been a file uploaded:
  # def default_url
  #   # For Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
  #   # asset_path("fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_'))
  #
  #   "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
  # end

  # Process files as they are uploaded:
  # process :scale => [200, 300]
  #
  # def scale(width, height)
  #   # do something
  # end

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  # version :thumb do
  #   process :scale => [50, 50]
  # end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end

  # Override the filename of the uploaded files:
  # Avoid using model.id or version_name here, see uploader/store.rb for details.
  # def filename
  #   "something.jpg" if original_filename
  # end

end
```

I've also ensured that carrierwave_direct, fog, mini_magick and Imagemagick have already been installed. May I know what else I have missed out? It almost seems like the mounting of the uploader has not been done properly.

Answer (score 5):

Managed to figure it out :) Just in case anyone has this problem:

I am implementing a separate model to hold my images instead of adding a column to an existing table. So the direct_upload_form_for expects the **column** (e.g. Image.new.image) instead of the **Object** (e.g. Image.new) which I was returning. I guess I was thrown off by the form_for part which usually expects an **Object**!

Comment: I'm having this problem. Could you provide the explicit example of the solution you discovered?

Comment: He's saying instead of just `direct_upload_form_for Image.new do |f|` you need `direct_upload_form_for Image.new.image do |f|` (note the .image).

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who runs into this error, you are likely not passing the correct object to direct_upload_form_for. Let's say we had a User model with an avatar column. It should look like.

Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
end
```

Controller:

```
def edit # Could be any action, but I always direct upload to existing objects
  @uploader = @user.avatar
  @uploader.success_action_redirect = edit_registration_url(resource)
end
```

View (erb):

```
<%= direct_upload_form_for @uploader do |f| %>
  <%= f.file_field :image %>
<% end %>
```

Notice how the @uploader object is actually the *column* @user.avatar, not the *object* @user. That's what the OP is talking about in his answer. It's just more confusing in his case because the object is not a User, it's a PostmarkerImage, which I assume is a model that only exists to hold images. This is common when you want one object (ie. a Postmarker) to have multiple images. So you create a model only for images, and set up a `has_many` relationship between them.

**Pitfall:** I was also getting this error a lot in production because I was forgetting to copy the code in the controller from the `edit` action to the `update` action. If the upload fails due to validation (like file type), you need to remember to set @uploader again! Similarly, if you have your uploader in `new`, remember to assign @uploader in `create`, as well.